# What is classified as a "Cantrip" card?

Tags: etherlords-2

You get an Artifact Blank and a recipe for Rod of Cantrips in Diamanda's Campaign, Kinet side (After playing through Vital/Synthet), and I would like to make it.

[image: Recipe of "Rod of Cantrips"]

Yes, I want to make a "Rod of Cantrips" but  I don't know what a cantrip is or what cards count as cantrip cards.

Comment: Cantrips are the basic spells; the ones you can use an unlimited number of times in a fight.

Comment: @fbueckert So... what's an "unlimited amount of uses" spell in Etherlords 2? (Cause there are no such spells in Etherlords 2. You even have a skill that allows you to use spells more than once, up to 7 times per battle).

Thanks for the explanation tho.

Comment: Eh?  No unlimited spells?  Guess I'm reinstalling Etherlords 2 to double-check.

Comment: @fbueckert the closest thing you have to "infinite spells" are creature skills (Like the Gargantuan Fungus that rests to deal 2 damage, instead of a sacrifice). Well, it's either that or summon->unsummon->summon->unsummon with... yeah, the "unsummon" cards...

Answer (score 1):

In Dual Mode, you can create your own deck, right? When you add a card into your deck, you need to pay some resource (green, red, blue) for it -- stronger cards require more resources.

Cantrip spells are cards which you can add into your deck (Dual Mode) without paying any resource.

Comment: Confirmed or speculation?